# NHibernate doesn't delete orphans in one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, orm, nhibernate

While deleting and adding works fine, when I update the Parent collection of child entities, the foreign keys on child records are simply set to null. I'd like them to be completely removed from the database.

So I've been trying `Cascade.All`, `Cascade.DeleteOrphans`, `Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans)` and nothing seems to work.

If I set Inverse to true on the parent but it causes the child records to not get updated at all.

Here's my code:

#### Parent class mapping

```
Id(e => e.Id, mapper => mapper.Generator(Generators.HighLow));
Property(e => e.Name);
Bag(e => e.Actors,
      mapper =>
      {
        mapper.Key(k => k.Column("Movie_Id"));
        mapper.Cascade(Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));
      },
      relation => relation.OneToMany(
        mapping => mapping.Class(typeof(Actor))));
```

#### Child mappings

```
Id(e => e.Id, mapper => mapper.Generator(Generators.HighLow));
Property(e => e.FirstName);
```

#### Parent entity

```
    public class Movie : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Update method

```
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                    try
                    {
                        Session.Update(entity)
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    } 
            }      
        }
```

Comment: Yes I did. The thing is that if I set inverse to true like many suggest and cascading to Delete Orphans + All, then the foreign key is left as is, not even nulled, and the record is not deleted. If I set inverse to false, then the foreign key is nulled, but still not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Update() to Merge() worked for me.